# Suppose $f,g,h \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$. Prove the triangle inequality $||f-h||_2 \le ||f-g||_2+||g-h||_2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha$ be a fixed increasing function on $[a,b]$. For $u \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, define $||u||_2=({\int_{a}^b |u|^2 d \alpha})^{1/2}$. Suppose $f,g,h \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$. Prove the triangle inequality $||f-h||_2 \le ||f-g||_2+||g-h||_2$.

This is what I've got so far:

$(||f-h||_2)^2=\int_{a}^{b}|f-h|^2 d\alpha=\int_{a}^b |(f-g)+(g-h)|^2d\alpha \le \int_{a}^b (|f-g|+|g-h|)^2 d \alpha=\int_{a}^b |f-g|^2 d\alpha+2\int_{a}^b |f-g||g-h| d \alpha+\int_{a}^b |g-h|^2 d\alpha = (||f-g||_2)^2+2\int_{a}^b |f-g||g-h| d \alpha+(||g-h||_2)^2$.

I'm not sure how to show that $2\int_{a}^b |f-g||g-h| d\alpha \le 2||f-g||_2||g-h||_2$, which would give the desired result.

Comment: Use Cauchy Schwartz inequality for this inner product.

Comment: I take it that $\scr R(\alpha)$ is the set of all functions on $[a,b]$ that are Riemann-Stiltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$? There are only a few notations that are common enough that you do not need to define them. And you should never expect that script or mathcal letter will ever be among them, as people use those notations to mean many, many different things. (There are a few exceptions - the power set is one - but as a general rule, this is true.)

Comment: Got it, and yes, I meant precisely those functions. Thanks!